# Alternative for binding into Polygon.Points

Tags: wpf, polygon

I want to draw an arrow. there is a line witch has a polygon at the middle of the line. I don't want to have a PointCollection separately for the polygon because it depends on the line location. So the solution I came up with was to make a converter and convert the middle of line X1,Y1,X2,Y2 to the polygon points.
ArrowViewModel

```
        private double _X1;
        public double X1
        {
            get
            {
                return _X1;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _X1, value, () => X1);
            }
        }
      
        private double _Y1;
        public double Y1
        {
            get
            {
                return _Y1;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _Y1, value, () => Y1);
            }
        }
        private double _X2;
        public double X2
        {
            get
            {
                return _X2;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _X2, value, () => X2);
            }
        }
        private double _Y2;
        public double Y2
        {
            get
            {
                return _Y2;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _Y2, value, () => Y2);
            }
        }
```

and this is my view

```
<Polygon Fill="Black" >
            <Polygon.Points>
                //bind to X1,Y1,X2,Y2
            </Polygon.Points>
        </Polygon>
```

I tried multi binding but you can't bind to the points. Is there any alternative?

Comment: "*you can't multi bind to the points*" is wrong. You can of course do that. You do however need to write a multi-value converter that returns a PointCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `PointCollection` one way or another because you can only set the `Points` property of a `Polygon` to a `PointCollection`.

Either create a `PointCollection` property in the view model and bind directly to this one, or use a `MultiBinding` and a converter in the view, e.g.:

```
public class PointsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double x1 = (double)values[0];
        double y1 = (double)values[1];
        double x2 = (double)values[2];
        double y2 = (double)values[3];

        // your calculation logic here
        Point[] points = new Point[] { ... };

        return new PointCollection(points);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Polygon Fill="Black" >
    <Polygon.Points>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:PointsConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="X1" />
            <Binding Path="Y1" />
            <Binding Path="X2" />
            <Binding Path="Y2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Polygon.Points>
</Polygon>
```